# waiting 2 thread are finished before to continue the program

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

When i click on a button, i would like to start action. When theses both actions would be finish, i want to start another action, this one need the result of both actions previous terminated.

Comment: Please edit your question and show some more of your work.  What have you tried?  What errors have you seen? Show some code samples http://sscce.org/. Otherwise this question may be closed because it is low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start a thread which starts two more threads and waits for them to finish i.e. join(). When the two have finished the first thread can do the work which comes after.

Comment: Since this seems to be a GUI-related question, it might not be a good solution. But without more details from the OP it is difficult to tell...